# ASP.NET Neo4jClient retrieving incorrect number

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms project which is using Readify-Neo4jClient and Neo4J Community 2.0.3, I'm getting a bug where a number stored in the database is changing its value when retrieved. Here is a picture of what’s in the database and what I can see in VS2013:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvMVF5TFpaZXJmNFk/edit

The code to retrieve the user is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<SUser> FoundUsers = Neo4jGraphClient.Cypher.Match("(user:User)")
    .Where((SUser user) => user.Email == UserName)
    .Return(user => user.As<SUser>())
    .Results;
```

Code to write to the database is as follows:

```
    long DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    SUser ss = new SUser
    {
        Id = UserCounter.SubmitAndCommitNewUser(),
        DateOfBirth = DobDay.Text + "" + DobMonth.Text + "" + DobYear.Text,
        Email = UserName.Text,
        FirstName = FirstName.Text,
        LastName = LastName.Text,
        UserCreatedOn = DateTimeNow,
        role = UType.ADMIN,
        Status = UStatus.NEW
    };

    Neo4jReq.CreateSUser(ss);
......
    public static SUser CrseateSUser(SUser NewUser)
    {
        //... 
        Neo4jGraphClient.Cypher
        .Create("(user:User {NewUser})")
        .WithParam("NewUser", NewUser)
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        existing = NewUser;
    }
```

Class is as follows:

```
public class SUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UType role { get; set; }
    public UStatus Status { get; set; } 
    public string pass { get; set; }
    public string VerificationGUID { get; set; }
    public long UserCreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UserNotes { get; set; } 
}
```

Any ideas on whats causing this?

Comment: If you strip down your user class to being just (for example) an Email and CreatedOn, do you still get the problem? Also - are you creating the users inside of a for/foreach loop?

Comment: @chrisSkardon yep even with the class stripped down the error persists. Whats strange is this error doesn't occur for some users (i.e. i create 4 test users and 2-3 of them wont have this issue). As per your post below i think this is infact a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right - I've got this replicating, this looks like a bug(?) in the way the Neo4j browser shows the data (both the current and older webadmin), so the data stored in Neo4j is correct, but it's getting 'rounded' (in a sense anyway) in the display, if you run the 'Get' query in the browser you get the '00' ending, this also happens in the old web admin:

```
http://localhost:7474/webadmin/
```

if you run the query in the 'Data Browser'.

However, if you run the query in the Console (`http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/`) you'll get the correct results. Neo4jClient is giving you the right results, it's the browser that is wrong in this case.

Comment: agree this looks like a bug, if i had to take a guess i'd say Neo4jClient possibly has issues dealing with 64bit integers as this problem doesn't occur in the neo4j console or with any other data types. In the mean time i think i will need to convert it to a string to store it or use something else for my purposes.

Comment: It's not Neo4jclient that has the bug - it's the Neo4j Browser! Your code is absolutely fine!! Your picture shows the VS debugger showing the *correct* value, and the browser showing the incorrect value

Comment: Yep you're right, i just double checked and the numbers into and out of neo4J are consistent although it doesn't appear to be correct in the neo4J Browser. my code is seems to be still creating inconsistent results but i don't think it has anything to do with neo4J.